# Trying to find a simple/elegant js/jquery solution to control user image positioning, rotation and scaling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, draggable

Trying to build an interface similar to Instagram's image cropping/positioning experience. Users are going to be uploading an image, and they need to be able to reposition the image within a defined frame. I'm sort of a noob, but I'm ambitious :) My hope is that someone can point me towards a working demo that I can sort of hack at.

The closest thing I've found is: http://matiasgagliano.github.io/guillotine/
But actually the functionality of an embedded google map is really closer to what I'm looking for.

Here are the features I'm looking for:

- Smooth zooming, draggable repositioning, rotating
- Native to desktop, but works on mobile (or at least would allow me to configure it).
- Reasonably light

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://fabricjs.com/

Its the closest you could get that i know of.

Comment: Thanks man. Fabric worked great.